# Creaming butter and sugar results in lumpy and grainy mixture

Tags: butter

I was beating butter with sugar to make a cake. I used President brand butter (80% fat) and it was soft at room temperature before beating.
However, only after few minutes, my mixture started grainy just like over-whipped cream. I decided to continue and ended up with pale and creamy butter but it wasn't smooth.
What did I go wrong?

Comment: That sounds normal if you used granulated sugar; if you use finer sugar it will come out smoother.

Comment: What makes you think this is a problem?

Comment: Over-whipped cream is grainy because the fat lumps in the emulsion have started to come together (eventually making butter). As dbmag9's comments says, your batter was grainy instead because of the sugar particles. If you don't want this, use caster sugar rather than granulated sugar (or a coarser brown sugar). In my experience a grainy batter doesn't matter for most cakes: it's more important that you beat until it's pale.